# Python kafka getting consumer messages in an async manner

Tags: python, asynchronous, apache-kafka, python-asyncio, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using `kafka-python`. I'm trying to define `for message in kafka_consumer` to run async in the background. Currently, it seems to me that it runs in sync thus blocking other methods. Does `kafka-python` support this? If not, what are my alternatives? I definitely need this to run in an async manner.

My code:

```
import asyncio


from kafka import KafkaConsumer


async def read_messages(kafka_consumer: KafkaConsumer) -> None:
    while True:
        for message in kafka_consumer:
            print (f"message is {message}")
        


async def main() -> None:
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('testing', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', api_version=(0, 11, 5))
    asyncio.ensure_future(read_messages(consumer))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
        loop.run_forever()
        loop.close()
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could use aiokafka, instead...

Comment: @OneCricketeer is it still well maintained and active? I looked in the repo and it seems relatively quiet

Comment: Haven't looked at it recently. You did ask for an alternative :)

Comment: Heh, unfortunately I was hoping for a fix :( So, the functionality I seek is not doable with `kafka-python`? I did check aiokafka and it worked, just concerned about the state of the package.

Comment: I found a Github comment in the issues from the `kafka-python` maintainer (from 2019) suggesting to use `aiokafka` if asyncio support is needed. Maybe create a new issue on either repo if you are concerned about lack of aiokafka functionality/features/support (lack of commits could mean the repo is stable, not abandoned)